# How to get repeating decimal in C

Tags: c

**How can I get the repeating decimal 0.99999999... in C ?**

1.0/9.0 will give me repeating decimal: 0.1111111, but if use 
double = 1.0/9.0 * 9.0 The result is 1.0

Thank you.

Comment: That is because `1 / 9 * 9 == 1` which is the result you got.

Comment: Postscript. Your posted code `1 / 9 * 9` will actually give `0` because it is an integer calculation: `1 / 9` is `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are running into is while 1/9 is a repeating decimal both in base 10 (0.1111..) and in base 16, (0.1c71c7..) when you multiply by 9 again, you get 1... as far as the floating point routines are concerned.  The way to get your 0.9999 in C is to break up the repeated decimal by subtracting just a little bit so it won't round back to 1.  If you only want to see 9s, you will need to limit how much gets printed out by some means other than the floating point formatting. This will do what you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
    double val=9;
    char disp[21];
    val=1.0/9.0;
    val -= 0.0000000000000001;
    printf("%20.19f\n", val);
    val *=9;
    printf("%20.19f\n", val);
    sprintf(disp,"%20.19f",val);
    printf("%.15s\n", disp);
}
```

This gives:

```
0.1111111111111110078
0.9999999999999991118
0.9999999999999
```

on my machine.

Answer (score -1):

This happend, because results isn't really 0.1111111. You can check this with `std::setprecision(numOfDecimals)` from `#include <iomanip>`

Here is little example:

```
double a=1.0/9.0;
double b=9.0;
std::cout<<a*b; //result is 1
```

From mathematic reasons: (1/9)*(9/1)=(9/9)=1.

If we actualy have results like this:

```
double a=round(1.0/9.0 * 100.0)/100.0;//100 for 2 decimal places: here is 0.11 actualy
double b=9.0;
std::cout<<a*b; //result is 0.99
```

[Example](http://cpp.sh/35a7n)